# Apply function to tuple of vectors to get tuple of elements (variadic templates)

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, variadic-templates, fold-expression

I have a container class which takes a list of `vector` or `array` objects (and stores a tuple of references to the original list of objects). Now, when calling the container via `operator()(size_t idx)` I want the function to return a tuple that contains the elements at index `idx` of each of the vectors/arrays.

```cpp
    template<class... Ts>
    class Container
    {
    public:
        Container(const Ts&... objs)
            : m_data(objs...) { }

        auto operator()(size_t idx) const
        {
            const auto get_idx = [idx](const auto& obj) { return obj.at(idx);  };
            return std::tuple<const Ts::value_type& ...>((get_idx(m_data), ...));  // <-- does not compile
        }

    private:
        std::tuple<const Ts&...> m_data;
    };

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<int> v1{ 3,4,12,5 };
        std::vector<std::string> v2{ "on", "test", "ABC", "house" };
        std::array<double, 4> v3 = { 3.14, 2.71, 99.3, 128 };

        const auto z = Container(v1, v2, v3);

        auto v = z(2);  // <-- does not compile
        return 0;
    }
```

For example, `z(2)` above should be equal to `std::tuple<int, std::string, double>(12, "ABC", 99.3)`. How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `tuple` and you need to turn it into a pack. The way to do that is with [`std::apply()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```
auto operator()(size_t idx) const
{
    return std::apply([=](auto const&... xs){
        return std::make_tuple(xs.at(idx)...);
    }, m_data);
}
```

`xs` here is a pack that refers to the contents of `m_data`. Once we have the pack, doing anything with it is straightforward.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. Side question, is there be an efficient way to check that all inputs in `Container(const Ts&... objs)` have the same size? I only came up with `const size_t N = std::get<0>(m_data).size(); auto check_same = [N](const auto& obj) { if (N != obj.size()) throw; }; (check_same(objs), ...);`

Comment: @Phil-ZXX `std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(objs)> arr{ objs.size()... }; if (std::unique( arr.begin(), arr.end() )-arr.begin() != 1) { throw; }`